# Parsing text into paragraphs with python (loop issue)

Tags: python, loops

I'm using the Google Sheets API and python to generate HTML markup from data entered in a spreadsheet. Sometimes the user enters long blocks of text in a single cell, and I am hoping to use python to parse this into semantic paragraphs when a new line appears.

Using `str.splitlines()` and a forloop I am able to get it to work conceptually, but the first iteration of the loop is printed.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

#sample text from spreadsheet
text = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."""

#break intro text into paragraphs
def pgparse(text):
    #split at every new line
    lines = text.splitlines()
    #wrap lines in p tags
    for i in lines:
        return '<p>'+i+'</p>'

print(pgparse(text))
```

Result:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
```

Expected result:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only returning the first line. Your second line is never even wrapped. 
Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#sample text from spreadsheet
text = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."""

#break intro text into paragraphs
def pgparse(text):
    #split at every new line
    lines = text.splitlines()
    #wrap lines in p tags
    return "\n".join('<p>'+i+'</p>' for i in lines)

print(pgparse(text))
```

Using a generator expression to wrap the lines and then join them back with `\n`

Comment: This does it! Thanks @DrioidX86

Comment: @rdas Thank you. I wasn't getting any love on my post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351645/cannot-get-replacement-count-to-increment-in-new-string-python but persistent and repeated searches finally led me here, and to an answer I could (with some fiddling around) I could actually get to work!  If you want credit for answering that one too, come on over and grace us with your wisdom. I'm not out of the woods, but now I have a breadcrumb trail.

Answer (score 4):

```
return '<p>'+i+'</p>'
```

This line exits the function. Perhaps you want:

```py
def pgparse(text):
    result = []
    #split at every new line
    lines = text.splitlines()
    #wrap lines in p tags
    for i in lines:
        result.append('<p>'+i+'</p>')
    return result
```

Comment: This returns a new list, whereas I need the two html paragraphs as strings, or even one without a new line. It looks like the second answer here using `"".join` achieves that.

Comment: Yup, then @DroidX86's solution is better for you.